# Regex match multiple digits after '-'

Tags: c#, regex

This seems like it should be easy, but I'm not so good with regex, and this doesn't seem to be easy to find on google.

I need a regex that starts with the string 'SP-multiple digits' and ends with the string '- multiple digits'

For example i have to match **'-12'** in "Sp-1234-12".

My attempt was: `[^*-]*$` -> This case matches everything after the minus but i need the minus included.

Answer (score 0):

For that digit and hyphen format, you could use a capture group for the part of the string that you want:

```
^Sp(?:-\d+)*(-\d+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Sp` Match literally
- `(?:-\d+)*` Optionally repeat `-` and 1+ digits
- `(-\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match `-` and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jelMCk/1)

Note that in C# you can use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` to match only digits 0-9